Cannot retreive customer's payment methods in Stripe
I have created a customer and payment intent in Stripe with the intention of charging the customer after the payment intent is initially completed.  According to this article, all I should have to do is add the customer id to the payment intent and add setup_future_usage : 'off_session', to the payment intent object.  Then I should be able to call the payment intent later and make the charge.
When running a test payment, I can see the future use payment intent in the Stripe dashboard. payment intent future use
But when I call for the customer's payment methods, I get an empty array.
Attempt #1
const paymentMethods = await stripe.paymentMethods.list({
  customer: customerId,
  type: "card",
});

Attempt #2
const paymentMethods = await stripe.customers.listPaymentMethods(
      customerId,
      {
        type: "card"
      },
    );

Empty list in response: empty response
The Stripe logs also shows these attempts with the correct customer ID.

The PaymentMethod will only be attached to the customer if the PaymentIntent had a value for customer at the time of confirmation. Did you add customer to the PaymentIntent when the PaymentIntent was created, or update the PaymentIntent with the customer ID before confirming the PaymentIntent?

I updated the payment intent with the stripe customer ID right before calling stripe.confirmPayment.  My process was 1-create payment intent with amount, 2-update intent with setup_future_usage, 3-create customer and add customer ID to intent, 4-confirm payment

It would be helpful if you included code snippets showing how you create and update the payment intent.  Is there a particular reason you don't have the Customer ID at the time of payment intent creation?

I found a solution.  I could only get the Payment Method to auto-attach to the customer if I created the Payment Intent with the Stripe customer ID.  Previously, my customer ID was added to the Payment Intent with an update.
